# Restricted Image Pull rights on Amazon ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

Lets say I have pushed following docker images on Amazon ECR

```
meinc/client1:latest 
meinc/client2:latest
meinc/client2:v1
```

Using IAM roles, is it possible to restrict pull access to these images such that

user1 can only pull meinc/client1

user2 can only pull image meinc/client2:latest

And user3 can pull meinc/client2

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot specify images for resource-level permissions.

You can only specify repositories for resource-level permissions, e.g. `arn:aws:ecr:region:account:repository/my-repo`

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ecr-supported-iam-actions-resources.html